# davidsonian semantics

Tags: semantics, reference-request, lexical-semantics

I hope everyone is fine. I was wondering if you could help me with some suggestions about which book(s) should I start with to learn the Davidsonian semantics, so that I will be able to read and write its notation and labeling system. Thank you.

Comment: Well, have you read Davidson’s papers on the topic? Aside from his papers I’d recommend Terence Parsons’ “Events in the semantics of English” and, if you want more formal semantics, Hobbs’ “Ontological promiscuity” (http://www.isi.edu/~hobbs/op-acl85.pdf).

Comment: And I forgot Pietroski’s “Events and semantic architecture.”

Comment: Atamiri, Thank you again for your suggestions.. They're not easy to understand at first time, I learned that concepts such as 'argument' and 'predicate' are incorporated into linguistic theory from the filed of logic. That's why I think davidsonian methods are complicated..

Comment: I don’t think they’re complicated. First order logic is actually relatively simple. Maybe if you aren’t familiar with FOL look at that first, but Davidsonian semantics uses only a subset of FOL, Davidson’s formulae are just conjunctions of literals. Should you have a problem with understanding a concept in formal logic just ask here.

Comment: Atamiri, Thank you for your consideration, I'll do my best :) good luck